# Message: chrome not reachable in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in python. I started working in selenium using python. When I write the below code, it is showing an error message. Can anyone please help me? I cannot find out where is the problem?

code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

result/output:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0bc80c8facaf> in <module>
----> 1 driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

c:\users\md ekramul mostaquim\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

c:\users\md ekramul mostaquim\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\md ekramul mostaquim\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```